# Size of java heap dump files

Tags: java, garbage-collection, heap-memory, hprof

My application server is generating .hprof files varying in different sizes  from 2G to 3G. Why are heap dump files larger than the memory allocated through -Xmx.

Shouldn't they equal to max heap size? which is when out of memory error happens.

Comment: The hprof has to record more information than just the heap. How much bigger is it?  There is a text and binary format, and the text format is much larger.

Answer (score 0):

It is not just the objects that it is outputting, it is also storing all the reference information for it to make more sense.

If processing large heap is a problem, you can use Eclipse MAT which helps you to index large heaps so that you can analyze them better.